# SciPy optimize minimize finds non minimal answer

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

When I use Scipy minimize in the example below, it finds a non minimal solution - can someone please help me modify this to find the minimum?

I have **four** constraints: 1) guesses of guess array must sum to one, 2) guesses must be > 0, and 3) any guess from the initial guess array that is over the threshold must be set equal to the threshold and held constant.
**Edit: 4th constraint** - no guess can be greater than the threshold.

I didn't use constraints for the last 3 constraints I have.  For constraint 2, I used a bounds.  For constraint 3, I did that in the performMinimize method before calling scipy's minimize method.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

def objective(initialGuesses, threshold):
    overThreshold = initialGuesses[np.where((threshold < initialGuesses[:]))]
    underThreshold = initialGuesses[np.where((threshold >= initialGuesses[:]))]

    overThreshold[:] = threshold
    sumUnderThreshold = np.sum(underThreshold)
    oppositeSumOverTreshold = 1 - np.sum(overThreshold)

    transformedGuess = underThreshold / sumUnderThreshold * oppositeSumOverTreshold

    thresholdedResults = np.concatenate((overThreshold, transformedGuess))

    squaredError = np.square(thresholdedResults - initialGuesses) / initialGuesses

    return np.sum(squaredError)


def performMinimizeSo(initialGuesses, threshold):
    overThreshold = initialGuesses[np.where((threshold < initialGuesses[:]))]
    overThreshold[:] = threshold
    underThreshold = initialGuesses[np.where((threshold >= initialGuesses[:]))]

    # Says one minus the sum of all variables minus the sum of weights over the threshold must be zero
    cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: 1 - sum(x) - sum(overThreshold)})

    minimum = minimize(objective, underThreshold, args=(threshold), method='SLSQP',
                       constraints=cons,
                       bounds=[(0, None) for i in range(len(underThreshold))],
                       )

    allGuesses = np.append(overThreshold, minimum.x)

    return allGuesses


def testCaseForSo():
    initialGuesses = array([
        [0.1],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.05],
        [0.025],
        [0.025]])

    threshold = .09
    output = (performMinimizeSo(initialGuesses, threshold))
    print(output)

testCaseForSo()
```

The minimal answer, as found by excel, is this:

```
0.09
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.050555556
0.025277778
0.025277778
```

Scipy minimize thinks this is the answer, which is close but not the correct minimum:

```
0.09
0.050526315
0.050526315
0.050526315
0.050526315
0.050526315
0.050526315
0.050526315
0.050526315
0.050526315
0.050526315
0.050526317
0.050526317
0.050526317
0.050526317
0.050526317
0.050526317
0.050526317
0.025526317
0.025526317
```

Here is what the attributes of the output look like after running scipy.minimize (as you can see, scipy thinks it found the minimum even though we know it didn't):

```
minimum.sucess == True
minimum.status == 0
minimum.message == 'Optimization terminated successfully'
```

Comment: When you use `minimize`, *always* check the `success` attribute of the object that is returned.  In your code, after `minimum = minimize(...)`, add `if not minimum.success: print(minimum.status, minimum.message)`.  Then include the output in the question here.

Comment: You may want to provide gradients. With finite differences you loose half the precision.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser - thanks. Attributes have been added in the latest edit.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen - that sounds like it might solve my problem.  Do you know how to go about providing gradients?

Comment: Having you tried adjusting the numerical tolerances, and see if that brings you sufficiently close to where you want to be?

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn Yes, I did try adjusting numerical tolerance, as well as other parameters.  Some of them can get me closer to the minimum, but the problem is that I need to find the minimum, not something close to the minimum.

Comment: What makes you believe the exact solution exists in a floating point representation?

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn, you raise a good point.  I assumed it would be possible, since it just seems like a very simple, straight forward optimization problem.  I definitely could be wrong about that.  It just seems like I should NOT be able to beat the optimizer so easily with excel.

Comment: Excel might be using variable-precision arithmetic; which scipy does not support? That said numerical error does not seem like a full explanation; the problem you are solving does not contain any precision-benders, yet it is nowhere close to machine precision... dunno

Comment: Looking closer at your problem... I dont think there is one. Your problem is simply very much underconstrained. The numbers you are getting are all < 0.9, and sum to one. There are many such numbers however; so thats reason enough to differ from some different implementation.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn So minimize just tries to satisfy the constraints?  I thought minimize would.... minimize?  Is there some kind of constraint I could add to reach the solution I'm seeking, or is that not really knowable?